# How do I create a save file for a C++ game?

Tags: c++, savegame, serialization

I am coding my final for a Video game Programming  course, and I want to know how to create a save file for my game, so that a user can play, and then come back later. Any idea how this is done, every thing I have done before has been single run programs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a game save file format in c++ using STL](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15134/how-to-create-a-game-save-file-format-in-c-using-stl)

Answer (score 41):

You need use [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) to save your variables in memory to your hard drive. There are many types of serialization, in .NET XML is a common format, though there are binary and JSON serializers available. There is an entry in the C++ FAQ on general serialization techniques:

- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization

There are libraries that can aid in implementing serialization. Some are mentioned in other answers.
Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c) StackOveflow Question for more information.

The variables needing to be serialized are probably going to be related to game state. For example, you will probably want to know this type of information

1. The player was playing level 3
2. The player was at X, Y world coordinates
3. The player has three items in his backpack
4. Weapon
5. Armor
6. Food

You wont really care what textures are being used (unless your player can change their appearance, that's a special case), because they are usually the same. You need to focus on saving important gamestate data.

When you start your game, you start as normal for a "new" game (this loads your textures, models, etc) but at appropriate time you load the values from your save file back into the game state object replacing the "default" new game state. Then you allow the player to resume playing.

I've greatly simplified it here, but you should get the general idea. If you have a more specific question ask a new question here and we can try to help you with it.

Comment: I understand what i need to save, but what i would like to know what is the exact way, do you save it to a .txt file in the project, those modified variables, or some other way

Comment: Yes, if your game is simple, a text file might be sufficient; you need to keep in mind that anyone can edit a text file and thus make their own save games...

Comment: Text file saves aren't just for simple games.  Paradox used a structured text format for save files for all the games they created using the same engine as the flagship Europa Universalis engine.  Especially late game, these files could be enormous.

Comment: @DanNeely A fair point, no reason you cannot use a text format to store lots of complicated data, but generally speaking, when your data is that complicated, the benefits of another format (binary, xml, etc) become more pronounced.

Comment: @NateBross Agreed.  The Paradox games were very mod friendly and used a similar (identical?) format for scenario data.  Storing most of their data as text meant they didn't need to invest in scenario editor tools for public use.

Comment: @DanNeely Great point. Using a text format means you might be able to skip building an editor, which can save valuable development time.

Comment: I like this answer, although one thing I'd add is boost::serialization, which is quite nice and has very robust support for multiple versions and so on. Plus, that can be combined with data-signing mechanisms to provide some level of tamper-resistance (doing an md5sum or an RSA private key or even using boost::uuid::name_generator to do a very simple "signing" comparison).

Answer (score 19):

Typically this is specific to your game. I'm sure you've learned about writing to and reading from files in your classes so far. The basic idea is:

1. When exiting the game, write the values you want to save to a file.
2. When loading the game, check to see if a save file exists, if it does, load the read the values in to your program. If the file does not exist, continue like you do now and set the values to their starting/default values.

What you write is up to you, it depends on your game. One way of writing is to write out the variables you want in a specific order as a byte stream. Then when loading, read them in to your program in the same order.

For example (in quick pseudo code):

```
SaveGame(FileInput file) {
    file.writeInt(playerLevel);
    file.writeInt(playerHealth);
    file.writeInt(gameProgress);
}

LoadGame(FileInput file) {
    if(file.exists()) {
        playerLevel= file.readInt();
        playerHealth = file.readInt();
        gameProgress = file.readInt();
    } else {
        playerLevel = 1;
        playerHealth = 100;
        gameProgress = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is nice and small, though I'd recommend putting in some simple tags for chunks of data.  That way if later on you need to change something that's normally in the middle of the file, you can do so and the only "conversion from old" you have to do is within that one block.  It's not as important for a one off assignment, but if you continue work after people start getting save files it's a bit of a nightmare just using straight bytes with position being the only identifier.

Comment: Yep, this does not generate future-proof save files. It also doesn't work for data that has variable byte sizes like strings. The latter is easy to fix by first writing the size of the data that's about to be written, then using that when loading to read the correct number of bytes.

Answer (score 6):

There are probably a large number of ways to do this, but the simplest that I always found and have used both personally and professionally is to make a structure that contains all of the values I want saved.

```
struct SaveGameData
{
    int              characterLevel; // Any straight up values from the player
    int              inventoryCount; // Number of items the player has on them or stored or what not
    int[STAT_COUNT]  statistics;     // This is usually a constant size (I am tracking X number of stats)
    // etc
}

struct Item
{
    int itemTypeId;
    int Durability; // also used as a 'uses' count for potions and the like
    int strength;   // damage of a weapon, protection of armor, effectiveness of a potion
    // etc
}
```

I then just fwrite/fread the data to and from a file using the basic File IO values. The inventoryCount is the number of Item structures that are saved after the main SaveGameData structure in the file so I know how many of those to read after fetching that data. The key here is that when I want to save something new, unless its a list of items or the like, all I have ever have to do is add a value to the structure some where. If its a list of items then I will have to add a read pass like I have already implied for the Item objects, a counter in the main header and then the entries.

This does have the downside of making different versions of a save file incompatible with each other with out special handling (even if it is just default values for each entry in the main structure). But overall this makes the system easy to extend just by adding in a new data value and putting a value into it when needed.

Again, quite a few ways to do this and this might lead more towards C than C++, but it has gotten the job done!

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is not platform-independent, won't work for C++ strings, or for objects referred to via references or pointers, or any objects containing any of the above!

Comment: Why isnt this platform independent? It worked fine on the PC, PS* systems and the 360.. fwrite(pToDataBuffer, sizeof(datatype), countOfElements, pToFile); works for all of those objects assuming you can get a pointer to their data, and the size of the object and then the number of them you want to write.. and read matches that..

Comment: It _is_ platform-independent, there's just no guarantee that files saved on one platform can be loaded on another one. Which is rather irrelevant for e.g. game data saving. The pointer-to-data-and-size-memcpy stuff can obviously be a bit awkward, but it works.

Comment: Actually there's no guarantee that it'll keep working for you forever - what happens if you release a new version that's built with a new compiler or even new compilation options that changes the struct padding? I would strongly, strongly discommend the use of raw-struct fwrite() for this reason alone (I am speaking from experience on this one, incidentally).

Comment: I'd still suppose that this solution is sufficient for the project scope. Chances are that any serialization library weighs more than the entire game. Also, correct me if I'm wrong but using POD structs in C++ will guarantee that the memory layout of an instance is as specified in the definition. Kylotan's criticism still stands, though.

Comment: I wouldn't say platform independence of the data is irrelevant for game saving - as more games become cross-platform and playable across multiple devices, players are coming to expect their saves to be portable. Irrelevant for the original poster, sure, which is why I gave this +1: I just think it's important to note limitations.

Comment: And James, it doesn't really work "if you can get a pointer to their data" because a C++ object's data may itself consist of other complex objects! Getting this to work with a `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<GameObject> >` would be fun to say the least.

Comment: @Kylotan I am sorry but I am still unable to find any instance I can think of where knowing the structure of a block of data would leave me in a position to make that data useless on a different platform. Also, I am -very- against dumping your list of objects directly to a save file. The structs I suggest are only to track the information you need to restore a game/level/whatever to its current setup after it has been loaded. You dont store the entire player, you store its health, its list of items, and not the entire item, just what type it is and what its current changeable values are if any

Comment: James: try writing an int on a little-endian platform and read it in on a big-endian platform. Or even just try writing a size_t on a 32 bit machine and read it on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: @Kylotan Why wouldnt handling endianness be something you handled when you ported your game to a new platform? Same on 32 to 64 bit? I am not sure how any other solution would not have to handle these exact same issues that you seem to imply only exist on this proposed solution.

Comment: ...because we were talking about data being compatible across platforms (or at least I was). The porting of the code process doesn't magically port the data as well - you have to decide which format you want it in, meaning a simple fwrite of the value on one platform will not match a simple fread on another.

Comment: @Kylotan How will 32bit and 64bit data ever be compatible with out code interpreting it properly on its system? Same with endian differences? Here is 32 bits of data, whether you store it in a 32bit int or a 64bit int makes no difference to me, the save file just contains 32 bits of data.

Comment: It's not about '32 bits of data'. The original poster is simply asking "how do I save my variables". If you fwrite the variable directly, then you lose information across platforms. If you have to preprocess before the fwrite, then you've left out the most important part of the answer, ie. how to process the data so that it's saved correctly, and only included the trivial bit, ie. calling fwrite to put something on a disk.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to decide what data needs to be saved. For instance, this could be the location of the character, his score, and the number of coins. Of course, your game will likely be much more complex, and so you will need to save additional data such as the level number and enemy list.

Next, write code to save this to a file (use ofstream). A relatively simple format you can use is as follows:

```
x y score coins
```

And so the file would look like:

```
14 96 4200 100
```

Which would mean he was at position (14, 96) with a score of 4200 and 100 coins.

You also need to write code to load this file (use ifstream).

---

Saving enemies can be done by including their position in the file. We can use this format:

```
number_of_enemies x1 y1 x2 y2 ...
```

First the `number_of_enemies` is read and then each position is read with a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

One addition/suggestion would to add a level of encryption to your serialization so users cannot text edit their values to "9999999999999999999".  One good reason to do this would be to prevent integer overflows (for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is boost::serialization because is easy to propagate down in your hierarchy. You only need to call the top object's save/load function and all your classes are easily created.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake I want to mention a c++ serialization library, that I personally use and was not mentioned yet: [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/).
It's easy to use and has a nice, clean syntax for serializing. It also offers multiple types of formats you can save to (XML, Json, Binary (including a portable version with respects endianess)). It supports inheritance and is header-only,

Answer (score 0):

Your game will compromise data structures (hopefully?) that you need to transform into bytes (serialize) so you can store them. In a future, you may load those bytes back and transform them back into your original structure (deserialization).
In C++ it is not so tricky since reflection is very limited. But still, some libraries can help you here.
I wrote an article about it: https://rubentorresbonet.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/an-overview-of-data-serialization-techniques-in-c/
Basically, I would suggest you to have a look at cereal library if you may target C++ 11 compilers. No need to create intermediate files like with protobuf, so you will save some time there if you want quick results. You may also choose between binary and JSON, so it can quite help debugging here.

On top of that, if security is a concern, you may want to encrypt/decrypt the data you are storing, especially if you are using human-readable formats like JSON. Algorithms like AES are helpful here.

Answer (score -4):

You need to use `fstream` for input / output files. The syntax is simple EX:

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
std::ofstream flux ; // to open a file in ouput mode
flux.open("myfile.whatever") ;
```

Or

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
std::ifstream flux ; // open a file in input mode
flux.open("myfile.whatever") ;
```

Other actions are possible on your file: *append*, *binary*, *trunc*, etc. You would use the same syntax as above instead we put std::ios::(flags), for instance:

- `ios::out` for output operation
- `ios::in` for input operation
- `ios::binary` for binary (raw byte) IO operation, instead of character-based
- `ios::app` for to start to write at the end of the file
- `ios::trunc` for if the file already exist replace delete the old content and replace by new
- `ios::ate` - position the file pointer "at the end" for input/output

Ex:

```
#include <fstream>
// ...
std::ifstream flux ;
flux.open("myfile.whatever" , ios::binary) ;
```

Here is a more complete but simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std ;

int input ;
int New_Apple ;
int Apple_Instock ;
int Eat_Apple ;
int Apple ;

int  main()
{
  bool shouldQuit = false;
  New_Apple = 0 ;
  Apple_Instock = 0 ;
  Eat_Apple = 0 ;

  while( !shouldQuit )
  {
    cout << "------------------------------------- /n";
    cout << "1) add some apple " << endl ;
    cout << "2) check apple in stock " << endl ;
    cout << "3) eat some apple " << endl ;
    cout << "4) quit " << endl ;
    cout << "------------------------------------- /n";
    cin >> input ;

    switch (input)
    {
      case 1 :
      {
        system("cls") ;

        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        cout << " how much apple do you want to add /n";
        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";      
        cin >> New_Apple ;

        ifstream apple_checker ;
        apple_checker.open("apple.apl") ;
        apple_checker >> Apple_Instock ;
        apple_checker.close() ; 

        Apple = New_Apple + Apple_Instock ;

        ofstream apple_adder ;
        apple_adder.open("apple.apl") ;
        apple_adder << Apple ;
        apple_adder.close() ;

        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        cout << New_Apple << " Apple has been added ! /n";
        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        break;
      }

      case 2 :  
      {
        system("cls") ;

        ifstream apple_checker ;
        apple_checker.open("apple.apl") ;
        apple_checker >> Apple_Instock ;
        apple_checker.close() ;

        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        cout << " there is " << Apple_Instock ;
        cout << "apple in stock /n" ;
        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        break;
      }

      case 3 :
      {
        system("cls") ;

        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        cout << "How many apple do you want to eat /n" ;
        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        cin >> Eat_Apple ;

        ifstream apple_checker ;
        apple_checker.open("apple.apl") ;
        apple_checker >> Apple_Instock ;
        apple_checker.close() ;

        Apple = Apple_Instock - Eat_Apple ; 

        ofstream apple_eater ;
        apple_eater.open("apple.apl") ;
        apple_eater << Apple ;
        apple_eater.close() ;

        cout << "----------------------------------- /n";
        cout << Eat_Apple ;
        cout << " Apple has been eated! /n";
        cout << "----------------------------------- /n";
        cout << Apple << " Apple left in stock /n";
        cout << "----------------------------------- /n";
        break;
      }

      case 4 :
      {
        shouldQuit = true;
        break;
      }

      default :
      {
        system("cls") ;

        cout << "------------------------------------ /n";
        cout << " invalide choice ! /n";
        cout << "------------------------------------ /n"; 
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 This is a very bad answer. You should format and display correctly the code and _explain_ what you're doing, no one wants to decipher a chunk of code.

Comment: Thank you katu for the comment you are right i should explain my code more well can you tell me how i format my source from the website cause i am new to this kind of thing

Comment: _From_ this site, or _for_ this site? For help in formatting the posts, you can visit the [formatting help page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help). There is an exclamation mark beside the header of the text area you use to post to help you as well.

Comment: Try to document what's asked; you don't need to comment everything. And by not explaining what you were doing, in my comment, I meant that generally you introduce the strategy that you suggest with at least a short paragraph. (e.g. "One of the technique is to use a binary file format with a stream operator. You have to be careful to read and write in the same order, bla bla lba").

Comment: And by using `goto`s, you'll get lynched on the public place. Don't use `goto`s.

Comment: Can someone help me for the formating i had read the help page and still not get it :(

Comment: [From the help page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Avoid using `<pre>` and `<code>` tags; use the back-ticks ( ` ) for in-line code or indent your code by four spaces (for text blocks) to make it look like code. Try to use the buttons provided by the answer textarea buttons. I suggest you hit the 'edit' button to see how I formatted it and learn from it. You can always use the 'edit' button to see how the post has been formatted (don't hit 'save' if you don't want to actually edit the post, click 'cancel'). Monkey-see, monkey-do. That's how you learn :)