# How would I attack saving a game?

Tags: java, savegame

In a lot of games, the player can save their progress. I have no clue how I would approach this and implement it into my game.
My only thought would be to make a new file called "progress," and add anything the player had done without saving, but I don't know how to add this to my game. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: [This has been asked before.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/25963/40264)

Comment: I would like to help you, but *"I don't know how to add this to my game"* is not a proper problem description. Please be more specific about where you are stuck in the process of adding a savegame feature to your game.

Comment: Also do you mean Tackle instead of attack? Poor game.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt that's C++, not java.

Comment: @TheMagician I'm aware of that and it's the only reason why this question is not yet closed as a duplicate. Although the language is different, the concepts will be the same. You should improve your question and desctibe what is troubling you exactly because right now it's really unclear, as Philipp highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just a hobbyist, but here's what I might do.

Create a "save game" button in whatever scene you want the player to be able to save from. When clicked, this button calls a `save_game()` method from your game class.

You can design this method to create a file with whatever structure you want. For example, you can store the player's position, current level, inventory, etc.

When loading a game, call a `load_game()` method from the game class which generates the game instance using this saved info.

Comment: One thing you might want to do is only save the player's XP from last checkpoint, special cutscenes, etc @dietestus

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade the only problem is in a roleplaying game

Comment: Yes, save each players stuff when and if they make it to a checkpoint @TheMagician